# "MSSQL\repldata\unc" Is it safe to manually delete old files that belonged to old SQL Replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

I am trying to see if it is safe to manually delete old files located under
"C\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.XXX\MSSQL\repldata\unc".

I realized that data in this folder is taking about 90+% of C:\ (OS) drive in VM.

I found that there are five folders inside here that belonged to old SQL Replications.

[image]

[image]

Is is safe to manually delete these unused folders?

Or is it even possible to delete manually?

Is SQL Server going to pop up some error or complain?